# Which minimum set of inferred triples are produced by OWL Union constructs

Tags: semantic-web, owl

Supposed i have only these 2 statements with the appropriate prefixes in sample turtle file.

```
:DisjointUnionClass owl:disjointUnionOf (:UndeclaredDisjointee1 :UndeclaredDisjointee2 ) .
        :UnionClass         owl:unionOf (:UndeclaredUnionee1    :UndeclaredUnionee2 ) .
```

What axioms are guaranteed to be produced with all tools/APIs like OWLAPI, Protege, TopBraid, etc.. and/or reasoners like Fact++, Pellet..?

- I'm assuming that all resources will be an owl:Class
- :UndeclaredDisjointee1 and :UndeclaredDisjointee2 will be **rdfs:subClassOf** :DisjointUnionClass
- UnionClass becomes an **owl:equivalentClass** to the unionOf UndeclaredUnionee1 and  UndeclaredUnionee2
- UndeclaredUnionee1 and UndeclaredUnionee2 become **rdfs:subClassOf** of UnionClass and the expression "*UndeclaredUnionee1 or UndeclaredUnionee2*"

I'm unsure because the http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/ states the following.   What are the rules for explicity declaration ?

The  5.8 Entity Declarations and Typing

Each IRI I used in an OWL 2 ontology O can be, **and sometimes even needs to be,** declared in O; roughly speaking, this means that the axiom closure of O must contain an appropriate declaration for I. A declaration for I in O serves two purposes:

- I exists — (it's part of the vocabulary of O.
- I is an entity type — class, object property,individual, etc...)

Comment: OWL is defined in terms of OWL axioms, not RDF triples, so a more appropriate question would be to ask what OWL axioms can be derived from these, and perhaps then what the RDF serialization of those might be.  Of course, the answer there might not be unique, since there might be multiple ways to serialize the OWL in RDF.  Additionally, there are a number of axioms that follow from the empty set. E.g., Pellet should still infer from these axioms that, e.g., `owl:Nothing rdfs:subClassOf :UnionClass`, and`:UnionClass owl:disjointWith owl:Nothing`, and `:UnionClass rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing`, etc.

Comment: Additionally, this probably isn't valid OWL, since most of these resources aren't declared as classes.  [5.8.1 Typing Constraints of OWL 2 DL](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Typing_Constraints_of_OWL_2_DL) says that it must be the case that "If a class with an IRI I occurs in some axiom in Ax, then I is declared in Ax as a class."  If you're not including class declarations, then this isn't an OWL 2 DL ontology, and what reasoners do with it isn't particularly well defined.

Comment: There's a mistake in your considerations about :UnionClass. That triple does not represent a valid OWL 2 axiom, since owl:unionOf is supposed to have a blank node as subject, and appear in tandem with at least another triple. See http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/ for how the OWL 2 to RDF mapping is defined.

Comment: owl:disjointUnionOf has domain owl:Class.  I thought at the very least that an undeclared Subject used with this predicate could be inferred to be an owl:Class.    I see the issue now in that the range of both predicates is rdf:List.  And that the domain of owl:unionOf is just the plain rdfs:Class.  Nevertheless, protege using OWLAPI does produce the bullet points i described.